# New Laravel Install (with Sail) has unknown auth method with MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have read a number of questions discussing auth problems with MySql 8 however my problem persists.  I removed ALL docker containers and created a new Laravel application, and here's what happened.

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

The above command installed the application as expected.

```
cd my-app
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

The above command installed the docker images and spun them up.  When I go to http://localhost I can see my application running, and I can access MySql from MySql Workbench using the default username (sail) and password (password).

```
php artisan migrate
```

The above command gives an error message as follows.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known [...]
```

In Laravel's env file I updated the value of DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1, then tried the command again.

```
php artisan migrate
```

The above command gives a different error message this time around.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [...]
```

After Googling about I **access MySql as root**, and try to modify the authentication method for the sail user, as follows.

```
ALTER USER 'sail'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

The above command gives as error message as follows.

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'sail'@'localhost'
```

I tried this from MySql Workbench, and from the command line of the MySql container.  I tried flushing privileges, but that didn't help.

I then tried modifying the authentication method for the root user.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

This worked fine.  However, I then updated the user to root in my application, flushed privileges, and ran the migration again, only to receive the same error message.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [...]
```

The Laravel version is 8.48.1 and the MySql version is 8.0.25.

How can I access MySql from my application?

Comment: Are tou executing those commands inside the docker container ? It seems you are not inside it

Comment: I have explained where each command was executed from.

Comment: First of all, the first command (migrate) you did not said were you executed it. Second, the `DB_HOST` must not be an IP in this case, but the name of the service. I am with the phone sonI can't see what's the Sail DB service's name, use that one. All the DB permissions errors are because you are not using the service name, so it has no access.

Comment: I execute migrate on the application server.  Where else would I execute it?  PHP is not installed on the MySql server.  Also, I changed DB_HOST to mysql and am back to the first error, #2002.

Answer (score -1):

This turned out to be VERY simple.

When you are executing artisan commands with Sail, you need to preface them with 'sail'.  The correct way to run the migration above is:

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
```

More details here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#executing-artisan-commands